# Browser not setting cookies (Nodejs backend and react front end)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, cookies

I am using a Nodejs server and sending a cookies that is not being set by browser.
I confirmed that the cookie is being sent in network tab.
[Network tab ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqBNn.png)

i tried mannulay setting cookies in react but it also didn't work.

and one strange thing is that when i refersh the page i stay logged in
but when i restart browser, it's logged out.

Comment: You can't access httponly cookies using client javascript

Comment: So how i am supposed to keep the user logged in?
local storage is obsly not the best option right?